# why putting blank line at the end of text makes different output? (hash function)

Tags: c, hash

**Source code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int hashFunc(char *c, int size) {
    int hashVal;

    for(hashVal = 0; *c != '\0'; c++) {
        hashVal = hashVal + *c;
    }

    return hashVal % size;

}

int main() {
    int size;
    char temp[60];
    char **name;
    int *entries;
    char c;
    int ctr=0;
    int i,j;
    int hashResult;

    scanf("%d", &size);

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    name = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * size);
    for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
        name[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    }

    entries = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    memset(&temp[0], 0, sizeof(temp));

    if(file) {
        while((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
            if(c == '\n' || ungetc(getc(file), file) == EOF) {
                if(strlen(temp) > 0) {
                printf("completed : %s\n", temp);
                hashResult = hashFunc(temp, size);
                entries[hashResult]++;

                memset(&temp[0], 0, sizeof(temp));
                ctr=0;
            }
            }

            if(c != '\n') {

                temp[ctr++] = c;

            }
        }   // end of while

    for(i=0; i<size; i++) printf("entries[%d]=%d\n", i, entries[i]);

    fclose(file);
    for(i=0; i<size; i++) free(name[i]);

    free(name);

    } else {
        printf("no such file\n");
    }
}
```

**1st input.txt:**

```
this is a
test file
for b4
a smll file but could
be effective
aaaaa
sdfghj
```

**2nd input.txt (just one more blank line after sdfghj:**

```
this is a
test file
for b4
a smll file but could
be effective
aaaaa
sdfghj
```

*** PLZ NOTE THAT THERE IS ONE BLANK LINE AFTER sdfghj IN 2ND INPUT.TXT**

**output for 1st input.txt:**

```
10
completed : this is a
completed : test file
completed : for b4
completed : a smll file but could
completed : be effective
completed : aaaaa
completed : sdfgh
entries[0]=0
entries[1]=1
entries[2]=0
entries[3]=0
entries[4]=1
entries[5]=1
entries[6]=2
entries[7]=1
entries[8]=0
entries[9]=1
```

**output for 2nd input.txt:**

```
10
completed : this is a
completed : test file
completed : for b4
completed : a smll file but could
completed : be effective
completed : aaaaa
completed : sdfghj
entries[0]=1
entries[1]=1
entries[2]=0
entries[3]=0
entries[4]=0
entries[5]=1
entries[6]=2
entries[7]=1
entries[8]=0
entries[9]=1
```

This program counts collisions from hash function.

Hi. I don't understand why outputs (from entries[0] to entries[9]) for 1st and 2nd input.txt are different.

Only difference between those input.txt is that there is one blank line after end of word, which is sdfghj, in 2nd input.txt

If you look at my code, I am preventing any blank line with:
 if(strlen(temp) > 0) {

but outputs(from entries[0] to entries[9]) are different. If I make blank line between words rather than end of input.txt, in this case outputs are same. only putting blank line at the end of the input.txt makes different output.

why this happens?

Comment: what did stepping through with a debugger show you was happening

Comment: Check your control output: `completed : sdfghj` against `completed : sdfgh`. Your program is hashing different strings in those two cases.

Comment: what editor are you saving it in? try using nano input.txt from commandline to save the file make sure you make an empty file first cause nano will save any marking special characters if they are already there. I have issues with newlines and stuff if I use textedit or more UI friendly editors when doing database work. I can put as many blank lines afterwards and it works fine when use nano